# Failed to configure SAPRFC + PHP5

Tags: php, linux, saprfc

Good day to all, as my title says "I have problems with congurar SAPRFC" use Linux Mint Petra + PHP5. Keep this [manual](http://www.rgiapratama.net/2011/08/22/saprfc-php-5-2-10-centos-5-4-64bit/), but when running "make" and "make install" me appears:

```
    /bin/bash /usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/include -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/main -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/opt/SAP/rfcsdk//include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c -o saprfc.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/include -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/main -I/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/opt/SAP/rfcsdk//include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/saprfc.o
In file included from /usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/php_saprfc.h:23:0,
                 from /usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c:27:
/usr/src/saprfc-1.4.1/rfccal.h:44:19: fatal error: rfcsi.h: No such file or directory
 #include "rfcsi.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [saprfc.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: check "report problem" link here : http://freecode.com/projects/saprfc_php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite it is and old question, I recently installed SAPRFC on a Ubuntu 14.04 box with PHP 5.5.9. As I found some problems on my way, I want to share the experience.

Requeriments: **RFCSDK 6.40 Non-Unicode 64bits** (must be downloaded from SAP Service Marketplace).

1.- Extract the RFCSDK in "/usr/sap/rfcsdk"

2.- Unzip "saprfc" (http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/) somewhere, i.e. "/root/saprfc"

3.- Install dependencies

```
apt-get install libstdc++5
```

4.- Edit the file "saprfc.c" line 47, ([seen here](http://nugraha.in/compile-saprfc-di-php-5-4-atau-5-55-6-di-ubuntu/))

```
change "function_entry" to "zend_function_entry"
```

5.- Now, we can compile

```
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

If there were no errors, we'll have the compiled file `saprfc.so`in the folder `/usr/lib/php5/20121212`. Now we have to tell PHP to load the library on startup.

```
cd /etc/php5/mods-available
echo "extension=saprfc.so" > saprfc.ini
ln -s saprfc.ini ../apache2/conf.d/25-saprfc.ini
```

Restart apache and see if it is working:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Using `phpinfo();` we can see working:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

upload rfcsdk 7.20 in /usr/local/

Upload librfccm.so patch in /usr/local/rfcsdk/lib

Extracted saprfc-1.4.1 in my root directory

download rfcsi.h (http://www.filewatcher.com/m/rfcsi.h.9944-0.html) and uploaded in saprfc-1.4.1

edit file saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c (on line no.47 changed function_entry to zend_function_entry )

in saprfc-1.4.1 execute following command

```
   phpize
   ./configure
   make
   make install
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Question was for No such file or directory  #include "rfcsi.h" .So with the above link u can download and upload rfcsi.h in saprfc directory.